# Error 404: Con Python y Flask

Tags: python, flask, error404

```
# Pagina web con flask

from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder="template")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello Flask'

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return 'test Flask'


@app.route('/sumar',methods = ["GET", "POST"])
@app.route('/sumar/',methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def suma():
    htmlCode = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("POST") # Obtenemos datos y calcula
        sumando1 = int(request.form.get("Sumando1"))
        sumando2 = int(request.form.get("Sumando2"))
        htmlCode = "Resultado: " +  str(sumando1 +sumando2)
    else:
        print("GET") # Mostramos HTML
        htmlCode = '''<form action="/suma" method="POST">
                <label>Sumando 1:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Sumando1"/>
                <label>Sumando 2:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Sumando2"/><br/><br/>introducir el código aquí
                <input type="submit"/>
                </form>'''
    return htmlCode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, port=8080, use_reloader=False) # solo acceso local
```

Al ejecutar este codigo me sale un error 404 con la ruta /sumar, no encuentro la solucion.
Lo estoy haciendo desde Visual Studio Code, ejecuto con RUN y luego debug, al seleccionar el link, y la ruta /sumar me sale ese mensaje, desde ya muchas gracias por ayudas o sugerencias.

Comment: Has intentado eliminar el duplicado que tienes de `@app.route('/sumar/',methods = ["GET", "POST"])`?

Comment: Hola si deje solo uno, este ultimo con / al final, y cerre y abri de nuevo VS, y al ejecutar con Run ahi seleccionas Flask, y ahi te da la opcion del nombre del codigo a ejecutar, sino sigue apuntando al anterior, era el problema que tenia, apuntaba al programa anterior .